# A better way to say "to engage in double standard"

Tags: phrase-requests

As is, it sounds a bit awkward to me.

Let me try to incorporate what I am after into a sentence. Just as Bush once said
"If this were a dictatorship, it'd be a heck of a lot easier, just so long as I'm the dictator.", I would like to write something along these lines:
"Double standard does not bother me for as long as I am the one engaging in/doing it".

It does not quite roll off the tongue. Hopefully there is a better way.

Answer (score 5):

It's okay when I have double standards, just not when you do.

Comment: *For the irony-impaired:* it is intentional that this is, in itself, the formulation of a double standard.

Comment: This would have been a winner if you did not ruin a joke with premature explanation. I hate when people do that.

Comment: @Job: Not everybody on the internet is as perspicacious as you.  It behooves one to take one's audience into account.

Answer (score 2):

Hypocrisy does not bother me as long as I am the one engaging in it.

Comment: Careful here, a double standard is not always hypocrisy.

Comment: @Cameron Sure seems to me that it is the same.  Can you give a contrary example?

Comment: @tchrist: One might articulate a double standard that is more lenient for groups one is *not* a part of; if one holds oneself to the higher standard, clearly one is not a hypocrite, but it's still a double standard.

Comment: @tchrist from the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_standard) for double standard: There is a distinction to be made between double standards and hypocrisy, which implies the stated or presumed acceptance of a single standard a person claims to hold himself or herself accountable to, but which, in practice, may be disregarded.

Comment: @Cameron I don’t accept Wikipedia as authoritative.You do?

Comment: @tchrist I don't accept it as universally authoritative, no. But I do accept the one sentence that I quoted as correct, which is why I quoted it. Why do you have an issue with it? Is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe: "A double standard does not bother me as long as I am the one applying it."

Comment: Agree. "Double standard" is a noun, so you can't "do" it. You can "have" it, you can "apply" it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't have double standards. Just agree with me."